# Passing JSP var to java method

Tags: jsp, parameters

In the following code snippet
I call the stringToValidURL() method in another file
this works, but now I want to pas the field var to that method
and also I want to store the return value in another jsp var that 
can use in c:out.

Hope some of yoy can help me out!

```
<c:forEach items="${results}" var="result" varStatus="resultCounter">
                <tr>
                    <c:forEach items="${result}" var="field" varStatus="fieldCounter">
                        <!-- Skip useless columns -->
                        <c:if test="${(fieldCounter.count != 1) && (fieldCounter.count != 5)}" >
                            <c:if test="${fieldCounter.count == 2 }">
                                <jsp:useBean id="bolLink" class="nl.iwa.project.api.bol.BolAPI" />
                                    <%=bolLink.stringToValidURL("") %>
                            </c:if>
                            <td>
                                <c:out value="${field}" escapeXml="true" />
                            </td>
                        </c:if>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<jsp:setProperty/>` action if that class has appropriate getter/setter.

```
<jsp:useBean id="bolLink" class="nl.iwa.project.api.bol.BolAPI" />
<jsp:setProperty name="bolLink" property="stringToValidURL" value="" />
<!-- Or -->
<jsp:setProperty name="bolLink" property="stringToValidURL" value="${expr}" />
```

Comment: Thank, I looks like it might work, when I'm home tonigth i'm going to try it and will let you know!